# An OpenCV function won't run in Pycharm but no problem in Jupyter

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, yolo

I intend to use `cv2.dnn_DetectionModel` for YOLOv4 inference as here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/17185.

However, I got error like others reported here https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/5366, (-212 Parsing...), and clearly this bug hasn't been fixed.

So I tried on YOLOv3 and run the same script for `yolov3.cfg` and `yolov3.weights`. It works fine in both `windows command` and `JupyterLab`. But it srill reports the same error in `Pycharm`. Could anyone give me some advice?

My environments: win 10; CUDA 10.2; OpenCV & contrib 4.2.0. But all these settings are the same in Pycharm, so it shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: The exact command that reports error is: `net = cv.dnn_DetectionModel('darknet\x64\yolov3.weights','darknet\x64\cfg\yolov3.cfg')`

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue and I fixed it by setting the absolute path for the location of yolov3.cfg and yolov3.weights.

Absolute paths would look like this:

```
String modelConfiguration = "/Users/yudhiesh/darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg";
String modelWeights = "/Users/yudhiesh/darknet/yolov3.weights";
```